# How to get audio source from sound file (mp3) ?

Tags: android, audio, mp3

I'm trying to get sound level from mp3 file that is playing. But first, I should attach that sound. So,

**How to attach sound from mp3 file as audio source in my code?**

As far as I know, if we want to get audio source from MIC, we can use this code below.

```
mRecordInstance = new AudioRecord( MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, FREQUENCY,
    CHANNEL, ENCODING, BUFFSIZE
);
```

And what about if the audio source is mp3 file ?
I don't know anymore for solving this problem.

Please, help me..

Thank you,, :)

Comment: You can't use `AudioRecord` for this. But you can use [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) to decode the mp3 file. See e.g. [this brief tutorial](http://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/) on how to use the `MediaCodec` API.

Answer (score -2):

try this code:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource("/mnt/sd/lalala.mp3");
AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(mp.getAudioSessionId(), FREQUENCY,
    CHANNEL, ENCODING, BUFFSIZE);
```

Comment: How is that supposed to work? The `AudioRecord` constructor expects an `AudioSource` as the first parameter, not a session ID.